# I have some questions about GridSearch on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, xgboost

So I was under impression that GridSearch of hyperparameters would be faster on GPU.

I opened my ticket here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/8041

Basically, my grid search on GPU takes 300x more time than on CPU, which I don't understand. Isn't the point of GPU that has a lot of CUDA cores and should act the same as multiple cores grid search on CPU? Why are all my CPU cores on 100% even while GPU is running, it says that it's using 416MB on each GPU available, while still having 100% CPU.

I kind of don't get the answer about small data? Isn't just that 1 combination of parameters gets processed on 1 CUDA in a certain amount of time (let's say 1 minute), so basically 1000 combinations on 1000 CUDAS should take 1 minute.

I installed packages with an anaconda environment. Tensorflow, CUDAtoolkit and XGBoost.

For example, why is here 8 times faster : https://www.kaggle.com/code/vinhnguyen/accelerating-hyper-parameter-searching-with-gpu

I appreciate all the pointers you guys might have :)

Comment: I am not sure why you are asking, the issue in github already has all the answers, the way you see how gridsearch should be implemented is not how it is actually implemented.

Comment: Since I would like to understand, the anwser provided on github is not extensive enogh, thats why I asked here :)